# Is there a way to force a form bind in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, symfony2-forms

I have a form type

```
class LoginFacebookType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('access_token', 'text', array("constraints" => array(
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
                new Assert\Length(array("max" => 512))                        
            )))
            ->add('save', 'submit');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'facebook_login';
    }
}
```

Then, I use it on the controller as:

```
$facebookLoginForm = $this->createForm(new LoginFacebookType());
$facebookLoginForm->handleRequest($request);
if($facebookLoginForm->isValid())
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //Debug form errors
    print_r($facebookLoginForm->getErrorsAsString()); die();
}
```

My questions is: If I made a request with a single param called "facebook_login[access_token]" i get all errors on the controller, like a very big access token, or not passing the csrf_token (This is ok). But if I made a request without any parameters, I get isValid = false, but error list is empty.

I want an "access_token field is required" and "invalid csrf_token" or something like that.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because form will not be submitted at all if there is no "facebook_login" key in POST data. You can force it to submit replacing `$facebookLoginForm->handleRequest($request);` with:

```
$facebookLoginForm->submit($request->request->get('facebook_login', []));
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Do you know if this method can be used with forms containing `file` fields?